# How to group in HashMap via stream

Tags: java, group-by, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have the following DTO and projection interface:

```
@Data
public class StatusDTO{
    private UUID productUuid;
    private boolean disabled;

    // constructors
}
```

I fill these fields in my repository:

```
public interface ProductDTO {
    UUID getProductUuid();

    UUID getProductCategoryUuid();

    boolean getDisabled();
}
```

However, when I try to create a mapping by grouping `getProductCategoryUuid` and its corresponding `List<StatusDTO>`, I get error in the `new StatusDTO(...)` part as *"UUID is not a functional interface"* and *"boolean is not a functional interface"*.

So, how can I build a map using `ProductDTO::getProductCategoryUuid` - `List<StatusDTO>` pairs?

Do I need `LinkedHashMap` as I tried below?

```
final Map<UUID, List<StatusDTO>> map = demoService.findAll().stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(ProductDTO::getProductCategoryUuid, LinkedHashMap::new,
                Collectors.mapping(new StatusDTO(
                                           ProductDTO::getProductUuid, 
                                           ProductDTO::getDisabled)
                                  ), Collectors.toList()));
```

**Update:** The foolowing approach seems to work, but I am not sure if it is a proper way. I use `LinkedHashMap` to maintain order. Any idea?

```
final Map<UUID, List<StatusDTO>> map = demoService.findAll().stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(
                             ProductDTO::getProductCategoryUuid, LinkedHashMap::new,
                             Collectors.mapping(p -> new StatusDTO(
                                 p.getProductUuid(), 
                                 p.getDisabled()), 
                 Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are getting the concept of **method references** wrong. Not every method call can be replaced by a method reference.

[**Lambda expressions**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and [**method references**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) should conform to a **functional interface**.

Which is an **interface** that contains one and only one *abstract method* (and **note:** the signature of this method must not match to one of the methods defined in the `Object` class).

Hence, in order to be able to use method references in the constructor call

```
new StatusDTO(ProductDTO::getProductUuid, ProductDTO::getDisabled)
```

type `ProductDTO` must be a **functional interface**. And since `ProductDTO` is a **class** you can't do that.

You can use method references only when function is expected. Since this constructor doesn't expect functions, even if you place it inside a collector, it doesn't mean that now it's illegible to pass lambdas to it.

Another mistake is that `Collectors.toList()` must be a downstream collector of `Collectors.mapping()` but **not** `Collectors.groupingBy()`. So the **overall structure** of your collector will be the following:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(function that extracts a KEY,
                      mapFactory, // <- resulting map (optional argument)
                      Collectors.mapping(function that transforms a VALUE, 
                                         Collectors.toList()) // <- downstream collector that defenses how VALUES will be represented in the resulting map
```

> Do I need LinkedHashMap as I tried below?

If you added only in order to try to make the code compile, the answer is **no**. Use `LinkedHashMap` only if you need to maintain the order in which entries were added. `HashMap` which `groupingBy()` will give you by default should be always preferred over `LinkedHashMap`. If you don't need it, then just remove the `mapFactory` from your collector.

Assuming that `LinkedHashMap` is required for your purposes, the collector will look like this:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(ProductDTO::getProductCategoryUuid,
                LinkedHashMap::new, // <- remove this argument if there's no such requirement 
                Collectors.mapping(product -> new StatusDTO(product.getProductUuid(),
                                                            product.getDisabled()),
                                   Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: "In regard to a map HashMap will perform better." --> what do you mean?

Comment: @harry Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). It says `maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries` - that is done to keep the order of entries identical to the order in which they were added to the `map`. And it has a **cost** because it entails additional operations when entries are being added or removed. The apart from that it act like a `HashMap`. That is why `HashMap` has better performance.